# Restrict a tab to open only once so that user can't create multiple tabs in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have a internal application where I have a tab named "HV". This tab 'HV' is coming from entry point from cencerto.

When I click on the tab 'HV', it opens the external application in new tab in the browser.

```
window.open("@viewsUrl", "HV");
```

There is a clinical risk if it opens multiple tab. For example, If I open patient1 in a tab1 and patient2 in tab2 then it is a chance of entering wrong information into wrong patient for clinician.

To avoid that, when clinician clicks on patient2, it should overwrite tab1 and displays patient2 information in tab1.

So, I would like to check if the tab is already open and then repopulate it with the second patient instead of opening another tab.

Is there a way to check this with jquery?

I tried below code, but it is not working as I mentioned in my requirement.

I have already invested 2 days and trying to find proper solution but no luck so far.

Please suggest me how to do this.

```
@{
    string viewsUrl = ViewBag.viewsUrl1;
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;         

            //function register_tab_GUID() {

                if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

                    if (sessionStorage["tabGUID"] == null) sessionStorage["tabGUID"] = tab_GUID();
                    var guid = sessionStorage["tabGUID"];                  

                    window.addEventListener("storage", storage_Handler, false);

                    localStorage["tabGUID"] = guid;
                }
          //  }

            function storage_Handler(e) {

                if (e.key == 'tabGUID') {
                    if (e.oldValue != e.newValue) {
                        tab_Warning();
                    }


                }
                window.open("@viewsUrl", "HV");
            }

            function tab_GUID() {
                function s4() {
                    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                        .toString(16)
                        .substring(1);
                }
                return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
                    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
            }

            function tab_Warning() {
                alert("Another tab is open!");
            }  

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This new tab is a browser tab or application tab?

Comment: @Basil, the new tab is a browser tab. The `HV` tab is within the application but when I click on the 'HV' tab, it opens external application in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot track browser tab link while you are in a different tab, it's related to security policy because it could easily abused.

But there is a trick to achieve this by using the help of `javascript`.

You have to assign a window name for each page you want this behavior to apply on using the following `javascript`:

```
window.name = "PageUniqueID";
```

Then on the link target that name

```
<a href="link" target="PageUniqueID">Go</a>
```

The browser will automatically open a new tab if the page is not already opened and will open the same tab again if it's already opened.

Comment: The point of answers is give you a hint on how to solve your issue not to write you a full code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo about how to judge if the tab has been opened:

```
<a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us" class="opener">Open microsoft.com</a> |
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="opener">Open yahoo.com</a>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
      var a = document.querySelectorAll('.opener'), w = [], url, i;
      for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        (function(i){
          a[i].onclick = function(e) {
            if (!w[i] || w[i].closed) {
              url = this.href;             
              w[i] = window.open(url,"menubar = 0, scrollbars = 0");
            } else {
              console.log('window ' + url + ' is already opened');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            w[i].focus();
          };
        })(i);
      }
    };
</script>
```

Result:
[image]